Do undercover cops sin by lying to the criminals they intend to catch?
The first sin on earth was a lie perpetrated to Eve by the devil in the garden of Eden, where the devil lied to Eve by saying that

Ye shall not surely die, but shall become like the gods knowing good and evil

Now scripture is authoritative on lying and condemns it because it's equates to bearing false witness against your neighbor. This is where my question comes in, when undercover police agents lie to the criminals they infiltrate in order to catch, do they sin? This is because even though they lie, they do something Biblically wrong for a long term good objective, to out a bad person behind bars.

Please review What types of questions can I ask on this site?

No.  Not every deception is the moral equivalent of a lie.  Deception is used frequently in sport, in warfare, yet it is not lying.  Criminals are not entitled to the truth.. it is not lying to deceive them in the task of trying to catch them. Politicians, though we hate it when they lie gratuitously, are nevertheless not obliged to give the truth at all times.  And parents are not always obliged to tell their children everything.  Generally, those in authority are not obliged to tell those under them the whole truth.  Families, political party's, countries, companies, and many other organisations have secrets which they are under no obligation to reveal, and sometimes are forced to mislead and deceive in order to conceal something.
A lie is when a person is deceived who has a right to know the truth because of their position of authority.
So Corrie Ten Boon did not do anything immoral when she misled German officers when hiding Jews in the house.
The midwives did not lie to Pharaoh.
In each of these cases it would have been a sin to reveal the truth.
For more on this see, for instance, chapter 1 of "Evangelical Ethics" by Professor J.J. Davis.

Well - it wouldn't have been a sin for the midwives to not lie. But the consequences would have been unpleasant if they revealed that they were intentionally going against Pharaoh's orders.

It would have been a sin for the midwives to tell Pharaoh the truth.. it would have led to the murder of more baby Israelites boys.  It would have been a betrayal of the trust invested in them by the Israelite community.

Them lying didn’t prevent deaths. Pharoah afterwards made a general proclamation to the people to kill sons born to the Hebrews. Hence Moses was sent down the river

Lying is not necessarily equivalent to bearing false witness against a neighbor; context matters. Since the Law requires at least two witnesses to establish a matter for judgement, bearing false witness is a perversion of justice. However, not all lies are done to bring harm or to pervert justice.
Furthermore, God even causes people to believe lies and has his prophets speak in parables so as to obscure the truth. So - like most things - it’s more complicated to judge the morality of a lie than simply establishing that a lie was told, or that you intentionally deceived someone.

+1 Worth noting that there are a few examples to prove the point. 1) the Hebrew midwives lied to Pharaoh to save innocent lives and God blessed them for it. I know some try to argue they didn't actually lie, but that's a clear case of eisegesis, a straightforward reading definitely sounds like they lied. 2) although it's not a verbal lie, Joshua was directly commanded by God to use deception against Ai.

But it's written that all liars will be thrown into the lake of fire

@SoFewAgainstSoMany a fair remark. But scripture must interpret scripture - and as far as I’m aware scripture nowhere universally condemns all lying or deceit. Not that it’s desirable - but it can be acceptable like killing.

Have you read the book of Revelation where God assured all evil doers of condmenation to the lake of fire, he does so even to those who practice falsehoods, even the agents when they lie to those criminals sin, for God hasn't said, good or bad falsehood but everyone who practises falsehoods

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I’ve read all of the scriptures many times - especially the NT. I’m familiar with the passage in question. The problem with your interpretation is that it ignores the fact that there is no general condemnation against lying in the Law or in the teachings of Christ or by Paul. There are specific forms of lying that are deemed sinful - and generally from Christ’s teachings we can safely assume that any malicious lie is sinful; a lie done with evil intent. And thus it is safely to contextualize passages like that in Revelation to those types of lies.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Furthermore, it is easy to think of lies that are done for good and where to not lie would be bad. For example: when the midwives refused to follow Pharoah’s orders. Or how about all the people in the Holocaust who hid Jews from persecution? Do you think they should have been honest with the Nazis that they were sheltering Jews? So you see even lies are acceptable if done for the right reasons.


The first sin on earth was a lie perpetrated to Eve by the devil in the garden of Eden

That first sin on earth was murder, and the lie was the weapon.
Lying is not a sin.
What one tries to accomplish by lying often is.
